# Set mindate and maxdate to same date allowing to choose time in datetimepicker in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, datetimepicker

I am trying set the min and max limits on datetimepciker to other control choosen date, date wise it is preventing correctly, but it is restricting on time also. Using angular material datetimepicker.

I have tried implementing this by giving proper attributes

```
<input mdc-datetime-picker date="true" min-date="ctrl.transactionDateTime || date" max-date="ctrl.transactionDateTime || date" time="true" type="text" id="date" short-time="true"
    show-todays-date="true" click-outside-to-close="true"
    placeholder="Valves Closed On"                                               
    format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm" week-days="false" edit-input="false" minutes="true" show-icon="true"
    data-ng-model="ctrl.model.valveClosedOn" >
```

this is preventing date selection i.e okay but also preventing time selection

Answer (score 0):

Use time=false option,than it only consider the date but not time.